# Show the content of other site in my system configuration in Magento 2

Tags: magento2.3, system-config

How do I show the content of other sites in my system configuration, Please provide me a solution

```
 <group id="general" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0"
                   showInStore="0">
                <label>abcd</label>
                <frontend_model>xx\yy\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\Extensions</frontend_model>
                <comment>  
                <![CDATA[
                <iframe id="mp-core-partners" src="https://www.123.com/core/sbc.html" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="100%" height="1700px" style="min-height: 800px;"></iframe>
                ]]>
                </comment>
</group>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove comment tag if you want to add the same in system config.
You have already defined frontend_model so create a block file with specified value in it with following code.

```
<?php

namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Block\Adminhtml\Form\Field;

class Customfield extends \Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        array $data = []
        )
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Set template.
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setTemplate('[Vendor]_[Module]::system/form/field/custom.phtml');
    }

    public function render(\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement $element)
    {
        // Remove scope label
        $element->unsScope()->unsCanUseWebsiteValue()->unsCanUseDefaultValue();
        $configValue = (string) $element->getValue();
        $values = [];
        if (strlen($configValue) > 0) {
            $values = explode(',', $configValue);
        }
        $this->setConfigValue($values);

        return parent::render($element);
    }

    public function getSelectedAttributes()
    {
        $options = [];

        return $options;
    }

    /**
     * Return element html.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement $element
     *
     * @return string
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    protected function _getElementHtml(\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement $element)
    {
        return $this->_toHtml();
    }
}
```

The create a phtml file

> [Vendor]/[Module]/view/adminhtml/templates/system/form/field/custom.phtml

With whatever you want to add like

```
<iframe id="mp-core-partners" src="https://www.123.com/core/sbc.html" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="100%" height="1700px" style="min-height: 800px;"></iframe>
```